# When do we need to use WebSettings.setDatabaseEnabled?

Tags: android, webview

I'm working with Android WebView and have a concern related to the Webview database

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setDatabaseEnabled(boolean)
[image]

According to this document:

`Sets whether the database storage API is enabled`

What exactly `database storage API` is? How can I know whether this `Webview` is using `database storage API` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the webpage you use it to display require the database API?  If so, you need to enable it.  If not, you don't.  If you don't know what page will be displayed so you can't answer that, you probably should be launching a browser rather than using WebView-  web view should be used to display specific pages in your app rather than be an embedded web browser with a poor UI for it.

The database storage api is the Javascript WebStorage API

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API you mean this one?